# How to override dockbar view jsp in hook?

Tags: liferay, hook

I have created a hook to override dockbar portlet..when I copied the `view.jsp` from `root/html/portlet/dockbar` in `custom_jsps` under META-INF compiler showing errors even after deploying the hook.

And when I restarted liferay portal dockbar notifications are unavailable. I am getting confused as I didn't find a clear example anywhere.

Comment: "compiler showing errors" => What is the returned error?

Comment: "a clear example" is the view.jsp that already comes with dockbar. It does exactly what it's supposed to do, and serves as a reference. If any other functionality would have been anticipated, it might be already in there. For your custom changes, you're the one to judge what has to go in there. Keep in mind that you're changing implementation details with a jsp-hook. From that point of view, jsp-hooks are changing functionality quite deep within Liferay, despite the relative ease of use.

Comment: @Gwenc37   What I meant by compilation errors was the errors shown by editor in eclipse...

Comment: @SwethaHarshini And what is the content of this error message?

Comment: @Olaf Kock Understood what you meant by...My doubt is that when I just copied the view jsp of dockbar in hook under META-INF directory and dint do any changes in it why dockbar portlet has gone unavailable in liferay portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments you're referring to errors that the eclipse editor shows when you add the view.jsp in question to your hook project. Unfortunately, this is expected: The JSP contains `include` instructions, e.g. to `../init.jsp` - and that file is not available in your hook, although it will be available once you deploy it to your appserver. For this reason, Liferay IDE (the Liferay-aware plugins for eclipse) offers to disable JSP validation in your jsp-hook. Yes, it's uncomfortable, but it's what you'll have to deal with currently. AFAIK the changes to the jsp editor would be huge to cater for this situation.

As of errors in the portal once you deploy an unchanged view.jsp: Please give the exact error messages that you see - either in your browser or in the log file.

You might want to check the appserver's directory and compare the deployed `dockbar/view.jsp` with the original file at `dockbar/view.portal.jsp` - the later file will be available once you deploy your jsp hook